# seed in nicta's rng lib in scala

Tags: scala, random

I'm using NICTA's RNG library and I want my RNG to be deterministic in tests. So let's say I just want to make below code always true.

```
Rng.chooseint(0, 5).run.unsafePerformIO == 3
```

But I cannot find any way to set a seed, and `run` method does not take any arguments. Can anybody help?

Comment: There appears to be a `def setseed(s: Long)` method on `Rng` - have you tried working with that?

Comment: it seems as `Rng.setseed(1).flatMap(_ => Rng.chooseint(0, 5)).run.unsafePerformIO()` work, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, [this issue](https://github.com/NICTA/rng/issues/20) has been open for almost a year, so I think you're just out of luck when it comes to off-the-shelf support.

The fact that `RngOp` doesn't provide either public constructors or a fold makes defining your own inconvenient, but not impossible:

```
import com.nicta.rng._
import java.util.Random
import scala.annotation.tailrec

class NextBitsRandom(seed: Long) extends Random(seed) {
  def nextBits(bits: Int): Int = super.next(bits)
}

def runWithSeed[A](rng: Rng[A], seed: Long): A = {
  @tailrec def loop(g: Rng[A], r: NextBitsRandom): A = g.resume match {
    case RngTerm(a) => a
    case RngCont(op) =>
      val nop = op.store.map(s => RngOp.store(s.imap(r.nextBits))).getOrElse(op)
      nop.seed.foreach(r.setSeed)
      loop(nop.extract, r)
  }

  loop(rng, new NextBitsRandom(seed))
}
```

A `fold` method would let us skip the kind of clunky-looking map over `store` and `getOrElse`, but this works just fine:

```
scala> runWithSeed(Rng.chooseint(0, 5), 0L)
res0: Int = 4

scala> runWithSeed(Rng.chooseint(0, 5), 0L)
res1: Int = 4

scala> runWithSeed(Rng.chooseint(0, 5), 1L)
res2: Int = 3

scala> runWithSeed(Rng.alphanumerics(10), 101L)
res3: List[Char] = List(M, h, Z, H, t, M, Z, H, c)

scala> runWithSeed(Rng.alphanumerics(10), 1001L)
res4: List[Char] = List(N, X, K, O, 6, C, L)
```

You could try submitting something like this as a fix for #20—if it were in the library the implementation would be cleaner, since you could use the `RngOp` constructors. It's a perfectly reasonable thing to want (and if I remember correctly, previous versions of the API did support it).

Comment: Thanks for response Travis. It's interesting but I just played with `setseed` as @Shadowlands suggested and it seems that `Rng.setseed(1).flatMap(_ => Rng.chooseint(0, 5)).run.unsafePerformIO()` is also working

Comment: @michal The "problem" with that approach is that this isn't actually an unsafe operation—you could even write it without mutability or side effects if the Java or Scala standard libraries had a decent random API—so dipping into `IO` and then bailing out is a little unsatisfying.